# sphinx autodoc: ModuleNotFoundError with sphinc-quickstart

Tags: python, python3, sphinx, document-automation

Just installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on a fresh virtual box this morning and I'm trying to re-invigorate a project I had running on my legacy VBox/Ubuntu environment. I'm stumbling with getting sphinx auto documentation working on the new VBox. My method of installing sphinx follows usual procedures:

```
pip3 install Sphinx
```

The trouble is experienced at the first step of the Sphinx tutorial in setting up a project:

```
[user@robot][~]$ sphinx-quickstart
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/sphinx-quickstart", line 14, in <module>
    from sphinx.quickstart import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sphinx.quickstart'
```

I opted to ask this question on here (instead of StackOverflow) since this might be related to configuration & environment. Anyone experienced something similar?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324393/sphinx-build-fail-autodoc-cant-import-find-module